# Creating a javascript that creates a dynamic total depending on radio box checked in html form

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

Dearest stackoverflow friends,

I am creating an online html form and have created a javascript function to dynamically (not completely sure I'm using this word correctly) display the total due in membership fees at the bottom of the form as options are selected. The total fee depends on one's membership type, country, and method of payment. It worked perfectly when all I was calculating was the membership type and postage according to country (I used drop down forms for these two options). Now I'd like to add the third term to the equation (the method of payment - one has a choice of cheque or paypal) but I can't get it to work. I'm using radio buttons this time.

My totalling function is this (without "+ getPaypalfee()" it works just fine):

```
function getAmountDue()
    {
    var amountDue = getMembershipPrice() + getExtraPostagePrice() + getPaypalfee();
    document.getElementById('amountDue').innerHTML ="Amount Due: $"+amountDue;
    }
```

The javascript I wrote to return the paypal fee is this (it's become very convoluted and I'm not sure where I've gone wrong and how to restart!):

```
var paymentmethod_Fee = new Array();
paymentmethod_Fee["cheque"]=0;
paymentmethod_Fee["paypal"]=2;

function getPaypalfee()
    {
    var paypalFee=0;
    for (var i=0; i < document.membershipform.payment_method.length; i++)
        {
        if (document.membershipform.payment_method[i].checked)
            {
             var selectedPaymentmethod = document.membershipform.payment_method[i].value;
            }
        }
    paypalFee = paymentmethod_Fee[selectedPaymentmethod.value];
    return paypalFee;
    }
```

The html for the radio buttons looks like this:

```
<p>I will make payment via: <BR>                                
<input type="radio" id="payment_method" name="payment_method" value="cheque" checked="yes" onchange="getAmountDue()">Cheque
<input type="radio" id="payment_method" name="payment_method" value="paypal" onchange="getAmountDue()">Paypal (Add $2)
```

Any insights into the flaw in my logic is greatly appreciated! I'm a javascript novice and radio buttons seem to be my nemesis (I'd like to learn how to use them rather than replace them with a drop-down menu or something I know how to do already).

Thank you!

Comment: Could you show a [minimal, representative](http://sscce.org/), [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we can play with to see your problem?

Comment: I hope this was successful: http://jsfiddle.net/Deeee/ccFL6/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Deeee/ccFL6/

Answer (score 1):

Arrays shouldn't be used to create mappings between items. What you're looking for is an object:

```
var fees = {
    cheque: 0,
    paypal: 2
};
```

As for your error, it's this line right here:

```
paypalFee = paymentmethod_Fee[selectedPaymentmethod.value];
```

`paymentmethod_Fee` is already a string. It doesn't have a `value` attribute.

Comment: It's funny because I used an array to create mappings for the membership prices and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use more than one element with the same `id`. Doing so creates **glitches.** *OVER 9000* **glitches.** So, don't use duplicate `id`s. Just don't. It is a maxim of web development. It will serve you well. Follow it to the letter. Or, you will have **glitches.** I am sure you don't want **glitches.** Rid yourself of **glitches.** Don't use duplicate `id`s.

(*preceding paragraph tl;dr:* Always have unique `id`s, or you get **glitches.**)

You should wrap your `radio` buttons in a `div` with id `payment_methods`. Then, use `document.getElementById("payment_methods").childNodes[i]` to access each successive button.

(By the way, two `radio` buttons with the same `name` are mutually exclusive, so the buttons should have identical `name`s but different `id`s.)

You are using `checked` correctly. It's just how you're accessing elements that's causing **glitches.**

Hope this gets rid of your **glitches.**

Comment: Ah! This makes a lot of sense. I've wrapped it in a div as suggested.... I'm still obviously missing something though.... I keep the ids of the radio buttons the same though right so only one can be checked at a time? http://jsfiddle.net/Deeee/ccFL6/11/

Comment: That is done through `name`. `id` is always unique, because it refers to a specific element. `name` refers to the form field, and is thus duplicated between `radio` buttons in the same group.